# How to Show Custom Post on different Single.php File in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

i have created a Custom Post type Movie, and Also created a page Movies and Showed all the movies on that page. Great….

“But the Problem is”, When I click on that movie, Its’ going on the same single.php page, and that’s what I don’t want, I want a Saprate Single.php file for this movie section and seprate others like news, videos, so tell what i’ll do for this

Answer (score 1):

Create single-movie.php file in your theme. Put custom code in there.

For any other custom post type use single-{custom-post-type-slug}.php

Comment: Hi bro, thanx for the comment, I know, i can make single-movie.php file there, which i all ready create it, but tell me that, which code i use for movie link to this separate post type page.

Comment: `the_permalink()` will output right one in the loop. If you have only post id than use `get_permalink($id)`. You can see results here http://ratnicisvetlosti.com in section titled "Najnoviji članci i prevodi". Some of those links lead to 'prevod' post type while other lead to 'clanak' post type (which you can see by hovering links), all output by `get_permalink` function. If url is like this example.com/movie/some-movie it will automatically call for single-movie.php template, no additional work on your side needed.

Comment: Thanx, but Ivan, Can you give me the code, I can give you the full detail of that...See I have created a page Hollywood and got a page [link](http://www.cineindya.com/hollywood/)[/link]. now i want that When I go to any movie link, then i want that link go to other single.blabla.php, Got my Point. I have few other categories like videos, news which is going on single.php but I want different layout for movies page, so please give me code for this

Comment: Have you actually created a custom post type? Or movies are just in a movie category?

Comment: And show your code man so I could help you! We're talking code here not concepts ;)

Answer (score -1):

heres how to do it. 
Delete everything in your single.php insert the following, and create multiple single.php files for your needs.
[note: in_category('id of your category')

```
<?php
$post = $wp_query->post;

if ( in_category(‘3′) ) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . ‘/single-photo.php’);
} elseif ( in_category(‘4′) ) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . ‘/single-video.php’);
} else {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . ‘/single-default.php’);
}
?>
```

Good luck ^ ^

Comment: This is completely wrong. Look here http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy for better understanding of which template gets called for specific type of query. OP is asking about custom post types ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types ) not posts in different categories. Happy learning, cheers.